# Passing returned variable to other method

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have problem, because I have method where I return a variable and I need to compare it, but I don't know how to get it...

**My code:**

```
public char setCurrency(String currencyToSet) {
    WebElement currencyVal = driver.findElement(By.name(currencyToSet.toUpperCase()));
    String currencyName = currencyVal.getText();
    System.out.println("Currency Name:" + currencyName);
    currencyVal.click();
    char[] currencyNameArray = currencyName.toCharArray();
    char newCurrencySymbol = currencyNameArray[0];
    System.out.println(newCurrencySymbol);
    return newCurrencySymbol;
}

public char[] getCurrentCurrencySymbol(){
    return currentCurrencySymbol.getText().toCharArray();//string??
}
```

I want to read in other method `newCurrencySymbol`.

***Updated:***

```
@Test
public void changeCurrency() {
    topNav.clickCurrencyDropDown();
    char nowa = topNav.setCurrency("eur");
    Assert.assertEquals(topNav.getCurrentCurrencySymbol(), nowa);
}
```

And I get an error:

> java.lang.AssertionError: expected [€] but found [[C@74f6c5d8]

should be `€` but is `C@74f6c5d8`

But when I print this variable in 8th line, it trow €, but not passing it

I'm changing currency (left top) on [enter link description here](http://demo.opencart.com/) and want to compare

Comment: Hi could you add the first method where you call setCurrency(). Welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: `setCurrency` has a return value. Either use it directly, or assign it to a variable. I'm not sure I understand what is giving you trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're comparing between a char array (`getCurrentCurrencySymbol()`) and a char (`nowa`). Former is an object whereas latter is a primitive data type. When you try to compare the two, you will get some weird values such as C@74f6c5d8 like you see. That's the address of where the char array is actually being stored.

I would suggest that you change from char array to simply a char since they're supposed to be currency notations. This ways, the comparison between the two values will be simplified.

Comment: String would be safest of all. Best not to assume/require all symbols are a single char, and to eradicate all such array/element confusions.

Comment: so should i use code like this to this two methods?

`String text = "foo";
char a_char = text.charAt(0);
System.out.println( a_char );`